# Interesting or unique types encountered?

Tags: programming-languages, types, language-design, language-features

What is the most strange or unique type you have seen in a programming language?

I was thinking the other day about a "random variable", ie whenever it is evaluated it yields a random value from some domain. It would require some runtime trickery.

Also I bet there can be some interesting mapping of regular expressions into a type system.

It does not necessarily have to be a built in or primitive type, but some random class that implements a domain specific type won't really be interesting just unique.

Comment: This might be better suited to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2):

Of course [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_type) is quite unique :)

Type `duck` is quite nice in *Boo* for indicating duck-typed values at compile-time.

Comment: I don't know Boo, but from the documentation it seems that `duck` is the equivalent to C# `dynamic`?

Comment: I just now saw this question and started to write some joke involving uniqueness types. Damn you! :-)

Comment: @delnan: Yes it is, but it sounds funnier ;)